# In election primaries, the voting breakdown tooltip misidentifies election nominations as "questions"

Tags: bug, election, tooltips, wording

Tooltip on expanded votes on nomination post says the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11?tab=primary):

> [image: Not a question]

But this nomination notice is not a question!

As far as I see in translation data base this is the [one source string](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?key=5bab7702b9f26dbd51a34f36d6329475) (with plural forms). So to correctly fix the issue only adding one more type (e.g. "nomination post") is not enough. Since different translation could be needed for different types of posts. This is just a luck that for "question" and "answer" we can share the same translation currently.

Comment: It is a post in the database, either it has same type as question, or the tooltip text defaults to questions when the type is unknown to it.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard we are all just collections of atoms

Comment: Even the pixels?

Answer (score 6):

"This is not the post type you are looking for".

---

An examination of the [source code](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/mod-elections/election.en.js) of the module responsible for the election page reveals that the `applyVoteCounts` function call, which adds the tooltip displayed when one hovers over the score breakdown container, relies on the `getLocalizedPostType` function call to get the appropriate `postType`.

The abovementioned `getLocalizedPostType` function is a simple guard that can return either "answer" for answers and "question" for everything else:

```js
function getLocalizedPostType($el) {
    return isAnswer($el) ? __tr(["answer"], undefined, "en", []) : __tr(["question"], undefined, "en", []);
}
```

Hence, everything that is not an answer gets the "This question has received ..." text (it has to be noted that during runtime the code calls `applyVoteCounts` from the "full" module ([source code](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js)) instead, however, this fact changes little to nothing as the logic is the same).

Another piece of trivia is that a given post's type is determined by the presence of a special CSS class on the post's container (currently — either `"answer"` or `"question"`) which is *completely* missing on nomination posts' containers despite such posts having their own type: `ModeratorNomination` (`6`) in the database.

Hopefully this helps Stack Exchange identify and amend the problem in the usual 6 to 8 time units.